# How to extend Active Directory user class schema in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have created a custom attribute in  **attributeSchema** using C#.
How can I associate that custom attribute to user class in Active Directory using C#?

Comment: See here for possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927309/retrieving-custom-active-directory-properties-of-users

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking to programmatically associate newly created attribute to user class schema.

Comment: What are you trying to do? 'associate' is vague.

Comment: http://fkazi.blogspot.com/2013/04/creating-custom-active-directory_27.html
want to do this in c#, the second part.

Comment: I don't think there is any native api to create custom ad attributes on the fly like you are wanting.

Comment: No, I have already created it using System.DirectoryServices library. 
now i am stuck adding this attribute to userClass schema.