# DirectoryEntry ObjectSecurity null reference Exception

Tags: c#, directoryentry

I try to enable windows account with this code but i ve exception in ObjectSecurity (Null reference) in this line ActiveDirectorySecurity userSecurity = user.ObjectSecurity;

Comment: What is wrong??? , i ve this code from this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827328/c-sharp-enable-user-account-with-directoryentry      , then i ve made some modification.

Comment: you are not specifying what line the Null Reference is happening at.. also wrap the code around a Try Catch {} and report on a true exception might help others to understand the Null Reference.. what that means in General terms is ..you are trying to assign something or use something that has not been initialized or New'd etc... also what is val & ~0x2

Comment: think you; i ve modified my code, its clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that your error would be on the 5th line in the code

```
user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val & ~0x2; //this will error
```

and if you were to debug it you would probably see the following error

Error Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Comment: no , i ve changed a bit my code, i ve exception in this line : ActiveDirectorySecurity userSecurity = user.ObjectSecurity;

Comment: no matter what he should get Error Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Comment: I would expect that `user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value` would get the result of `val & ~0x2`, whatever that is.  What's the problem there?

Comment: I know it's an assignment .. but I can almost bet that's where the error is.. still waiting on the OP to respond as well

Comment: I've found another may to enable account with PrincipaleContext, I'found the solution. think you everyone.

Comment: I believe that's what I suggested to you the first time.. LOL glad that you could figure it out..